# NSolve for high degree univariate polynomials

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a high degree univariate polynomial using Mathematica's NSolve command. But when I plug the solutions generated by Mathematica back to the equations, the equations are massive numbers and not even close to zero.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r := Rationalize[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]]
randompol[n_, i_] := Sum[r Sqrt[Binomial[n, j]] x^j, {j, 0, n}]

e= randompol[100,1];

SetSystemOptions["NSolveOptions" -> {"Tolerance" -> 10^(-10)}];
sol = Solve[e == 0, x];

e/.sol
```

which gives some of the entries as big as `-1.8513*10^56`

I don't know what other method can be used to solve high degree polynomials.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards,
-John

Comment: (1) It looks like you used `Solve` rather than `NSolve`. (2) Setting that `SystemOption` will not be of any use here.

Comment: So which one is better for solving high degree univariate polynomials? Solve or NSolve?

Comment: I would use NRoots, with possible nondefault settings for `PrecisionGoal`. But it won't matter if the problem is ill conditioned at the precision of, say, the input (which is `MachinePrecision` in this example; you might want to check what that `r` is actually doing).

Comment: Estimating the max. error in `x`, I get, with `SeedRandom[1]` before executing your code, `{e/D[e, x]} /. sol // Abs // Max` --> `1.62988*10^-14`, which is pretty good.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Which algorithm does Solve and NSolve use when solving univariate polynomials?

Comment: Depending on option settings `Solve` might try to find radical solutions or else deliver `Root` objects, provided input is exact. Else, like `NSolve`, it will call on `NRoots`. Per documentation (Help > Documentation Center > NRoots), that function supports `method` option settings of  `"Aberth"`, `"CompanionMatrix"`, and `"JenkinsTraub"`.

Answer (score 6):

I did a few things:

(1)  Set the second argument of `Rationalize` to a definite, but arbitrary, value so that exact numbers (fractions) were produced by `Rationalize`.  Your original code did not give exact numbers for `r`.

(2)  Forced the coefficients of the polynomial to have high precision.

(3)  Dropped the second argument of `randompol` .   Deleted the `SetSystemsOptions`.

(4)  Set a high `Working Precision -> 200` within NSolve.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

r := Rationalize[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 0.001]


randompol[n_] := 

Sum[r SetPrecision[Sqrt[Binomial[n, j]], 1000] x^j, {j, 0, n}] 


e = randompol[100];

sol = NSolve[e == 0, x, WorkingPrecision -> 200]; 

Abs[e /. sol] // Max

(* 0.*10^-103 *)
```

Which indicates that e is much closer to zero than when I used your original code.  I was suspicious of such quick and easy success, but a look at the `sol` values themselves suggests that they are indeed very high precision numbers.

```
sol[[1]]

{x -> -6.0238372136976606502260060478459892247764184751597217356329032\

6202362152948359151728116621315272069788936311451308262538189004899677\

26114562119851606529164803119604073806915565538453032032195787093638 \

- 1.520416566625392687364937426390455945886297726051920478299290947504\

9036377745161941667006869410482430785120127207233197413002926845477907\

689127706303421233595275524517422427858590001778013216673664575 I}
```

P.S.  Yes, I considered a different problem than the one you posed, in order to introduce a level of discreteness to the polynomial coefficients.  If you evaluate:

```
r := Rationalize[s = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]]
{r, s, r - s, Precision[r], Precision[s], Precision[r - s]}

(*  {-0.203065, -0.203065, 0., MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision,  *)
(*    MachinePrecision}                                             *)
```

you can see that `Rationalize`, without a second argument, doesn't do anything to a machine number as its first argument; the result is just a machine number, not a rational.  So, rationals were not being produced in your original code.

The documentation of `Rationalize` seems to suggest that the smallest value for its second argument is 0.  In that case, the denominators of the rationals produced by `Rationalize` seem to have 9 decimal digits, at most, in which case setting `WorkingPrecision->200` in `NSolve` will produce the kind of good agreement for `Abs[e /. sol] // Max` shown earlier.  With 0 as the second argument of `Rationalize`, the `SetPrecision[ . . . ,1000]` I inserted into the `Sum` expression of your original code was unnecessary.  This would have been more a more direct code response:

```
r := Rationalize[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 0]
randompol[n_] := Sum[r Sqrt[Binomial[n, j]] x^j, {j, 0, n}] 
e = randompol[100];
sol = NSolve[e == 0, x, WorkingPrecision -> 200];
Abs[e /. sol] // Max
(*  0.*10^-21  *)
```

Thank you for commenting on my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But by rationalizing the coefficient by approximating it with 0.0001 precision, aren't you solving a different problem than the original one?!

Comment: Could rationalize it to tighter tolerance, say 10^(-100). I'm not clear on what is meant by "solving a different problem" though. It's certainly different from what's there if no rationalization is done-- any rationalizing will move it to a "nearby' problem. But that was true of the original formulation, when rationalizing actually takes place (which it does, on some coefficients).

Comment: In principle, the tolerance on the coefficients could be set tighter, to 10^-100, as Daniel suggests, but Mathematica's `Rationalize` function isn't up to that task.  It can't do much better than 10^-10, as indicated in the P.S. to my original answer.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about `Rationalize` not being able to get within 10^(-100). The numbers in question had around 16 decimal places so these can typically be approximated by rationals with 10 or fewer digits in numerator and denominator (worst case: 16 digits). But that doesn't mean we fell outside the 10^(-100) bound in terms of how close we are.

Comment: You are correct.  I was only making the point that numbers with only 16 digits of precision are not going to get turned into rationals with 100-digit denominators by `Rationalize`.  To see what `Rationalize` does, I ran

Comment: `lis = Tally[
   ParallelTable[
    Length[IntegerDigits[
      Denominator[Rationalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]]]], {10^7}]] // 
  Union` with output `(* {{5, 1}, {6, 363}, {7, 33752}, {8, 3608865}, {9, 6064836}, {10, 
  286763}, {11, 5332}, {12, 87}, {13, 1}} *)`, which didn't find any 16-digit denominators, but they would be there in a large sample.  ListLogPlot of output is nice.

Comment: My question is, does the tighter tolerance 10^(-100) puts 'closer' to the original floating point problem than the tolerance 10^(-10) ?

Answer (score 5):

### NSolve works fine

Basically, there is nothing wrong with the result that `Solve`/`NSolve` produces, or at least the errors are slight.  The number `10^166` may not seem that close to zero, but that depends on whether it is compared with `1` or `10^175`.  Since `NSolve` solves for `x`, the best you can hope for is that all the bits in the machine number for `x` are correct.  In practice, the last few bits may be wrong due to round-off error in computing function values.

#### On SetPrecision[.., Infinity] and epsilon

Let me review a few facts about machine floating-point numbers that I wish to refer to in my explanation.  A (binary) machine real `x` is a rational number of the form `x0 = mantissa * 2^exponent`, where `mantissa` is represented with a fixed number of bits.  Changing the lowest-order bit corresponds to changing `x` by the smallest amount `ϵ` possible.  The real number `x` can be thought of as representing a real number that lies between `x0 ± ϵ/2`, with a maximum uncertainty of `ϵ/2`; the point-estimate `x0` is the number used in computation.  In a computational process there can be round-off error that gets propagated resulting in a number `x` that has a uncertainty greater than `ϵ/2`.  In *Mathematica*, the `ϵ` for the number `x = 1` is given by `$MachineEpsilon` (on my machine, `$MachineEpsilon == 2.220446049250313*^-16 == 2^(-52)`).  For a number `x`, one can estimate the corresponding `ϵ` with `$MachineEpsilon * x`.  One can get the exact number `x0` with `x0 = SetPrecision[x, Infinity]`.

### <s>Two</s> Three explanations

There are <s>two</s> three ways to explain why `e /. x -> sol[[1]]` can result in a number larger than `10^166` when `sol[[1]]` gives the best possible approximation of the root (at machine precision).  For the sake of reproducibility, here is the code I used from the OP, with a slight change (`Rationalize` did nothing on the coefficients generated):

```
SeedRandom[1];
(*r := Rationalize[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,1]]];*)
r := RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
e = randompol[100, 1];
sol = NSolve[e == 0, x];
```

#### Update: Using Solve

If we use `Solve` on the exact equation, we can check these solutions against the ones returned by `NSolve`.  The equation has to have exact coefficients or `Solve` uses numerical techniques.

```
solexact = Solve[SetPrecision[e, Infinity] == 0, x];

(x /. sol) == Sort@N[x /. solexact]
Sort@N[x /. solexact] - (x /. sol) // Abs // Max
(*
  True
  3.55271*10^-15
*)
```

Here we see `Solve` did in fact return solutions (of course!).

```
ParallelMap[FullSimplify, 
  SetPrecision[e, Infinity] /. solexact] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {77.192719, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0}}
*)
```

**Perhaps the answer should stop here.** Originally I was interested in explaining the numerics because this issue has come up before.  I thought having an explanation of why `NSolve` *appears* to have done a bad job but in fact did a good job might be helpful.

#### The propagation of the error in x in the value of the polynomial

First, if `y = f[x]`, then for a given error `dx` in `x`, the corresponding error `dy` in `y` is approximated by

```
dy = f'[x] dx
```

The size of `dy` evidently depends on the size of `f'[x]`.  Let us take `sol[[1]]` as an example (it produces the greatest value of `e`).  If `dx` is on the order of `0.5 $MachineEpsilon * x` and the derivative `D[e, x] /. sol[[1]]` of the OP's equation is on the order of `10^180`, then `dy` will be on the order of

```
Abs[D[e, x] (0.5 $MachineEpsilon*x)] /. sol[[1]]
(*
  1.77676*10^166
*)
```

The magnitude of `e`, which is the error from `0`, is about twice that,

```
e /. sol[[1]]
(*
  -3.82848*10^166
*)
```

suggesting either round-off error in the calculation of `e` or error in the result of `NSolve`.  If the error is due to `NSolve`, the error is not much since the uncertainty in `x` appears to be a little more than `$MachineEpsilon * x`.  It appears that the root in `sol[[1]]` might be off in its last binary bit from what is optimal.  In any case, it's a good-looking result.

#### Precision and round-off error in evaluating the polynomial

But not so fast.  A second way to analyze the situation is as follows.  *Mathematica* can track precision, if so-called arbitrary-precision numbers are used.  We can turn precision-tracking on, by setting the precision to `$MachinePrecision`.

```
SetPrecision[e, $MachinePrecision] /. SetPrecision[sol[[1]], $MachinePrecision]
Accuracy[%]
(*
  0.*10^168
  -168.799
*)
```

*Mathematica* is indicating that the result is `0` within an error less than about ±10^168.  Our original value `-3.8*^166` for `e /. sol[[1]]` is well within that error.  What is happening is a tremendous loss of precision in computing `e /. sol[[1]]`.   If we set the precision high enough, we can calculate the value of `e` at the (exact rational) number computed for `sol[[1]]`.

```
SetPrecision[e, 50] /. SetPrecision[sol[[1]], 50];
Precision[%]     (* check precision *)
N[%%]            (* print as a machine Real *)
(*
  31.3568
  -1.28981*10^166
*)
```

By controlling the round-off error in calculating `e`, we see that the value for `e` is within the estimated maximum error `1.77676 * 10^166`.  This suggests that the computed value for `x` is the best possible.  We can check that with the number within `±ϵ`.  They give values of `e` further from zero:

```
With[{eps = SetPrecision[$MachineEpsilon, 50], 
  sol = SetPrecision[sol[[1]], 50]},
 {SetPrecision[e, 50] /. x -> (x - eps x /. sol),
  SetPrecision[e, 50] /. x -> (x + eps x /. sol)} // N
 ]
(*
  {-4.84333*10^166, 2.2637*10^166}
*)
```

Thus we see that `NSolve` actually computed the best approximation to the real root for the case `sol[[1]]`.

### On the accuracy of the solutions

With the other roots, it is more or less the same, that (1) the computed number for `x` is the best or nearly best possible approximation of the root and (2) the value of `e` is due to a round-off error and/or a large value of `D[e, x]`.  About half give the best possible solution.  In most other cases, the error is in the last one or two bits, but that might not be surprising given the sort of numerical difficulty `e` presents.  The worst cases are the complex conjugate pair `sol[[{57, 58}]]` which are `12 ϵ` away from the <s>best</s> **exact** solution (as found by <s>`FindRoot`</s> `Solve`).  Below we see the value of `e` is less at `x - 12 eps`;

```
SetPrecision[e, 50] /. SetPrecision[sol[[57]], 50] // Abs // N
With[{eps = 2^Floor@Log2@Abs[$MachineEpsilon Re[x]] /. sol[[57]]},
   SetPrecision[e, 50] /. 
    x -> (x - 12 eps /. SetPrecision[sol[[57]], 50])
   ] // Abs // N
(*
  1.25526*10^46
  2.91146*10^45
*)
```

The code below finds how far each solution found by `NSolve` is from each root (measured in relative epsilons).

```
dxeps = MapThread[
  Function[{x, xexact}, 
   Through[{Re, Im}[(xexact) - (x)]] / 
      {2^Floor@Log2@Abs[$MachineEpsilon Re[x0]], 
       2^Floor@Log2@Abs[$MachineEpsilon Im[x0]]} /. x0 -> x
   ],
  {x /. sol, Sort@N[x /. solexact]}
  ]
```

48 of 100 solutions are best possible; the worst cases are solutions 57/58.

```
Count[dxeps, {0., 0.}]
(*
  48
*)

Position[#, Max@#] &@ Abs @ dxeps
(*
  {{57, 1}, {58, 1}}
*)
```

Distribution of errors:

```
Labeled[
 Histogram[Flatten @ Abs @ dxeps],
 Style["Errors in real and imaginary parts of roots (epsilons)", "Label"]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Getting more accurate results

**Update**: Perhaps one should just use `Solve` as above.  I'll leave the explanation below because I find it interesting, even if it's rather useless in this case.

As mentioned by [user15996](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/15996/user15996), to get solutions that produce values for `e` that are zero to some number of digits of accuracy, greater working precision is needed.  First, we will need to set the precision of the coefficients of the polynomial `e` to be exact (or of sufficient precision), which I'll call `eP`.   As an example let's consider `sol[[57]]`.  We see below that there is a deficit of almost 49 digits, that is, *Mathematica* is telling us that the value is zero with an error less than `10^49`.  So if we use a `WorkingPrecision` of 49 digits plus `$MachinePrecision`, we should end up with an accuracy around `0` digits.  It's a little tricky to get exactly `0` because the real and imaginary parts have different accuracies.  We can increase the `WorkingPrecision` to get a positive number of significant digtis.

```
eP = SetPrecision[e, Infinity];

eP /. SetPrecision[sol[[57]], $MachinePrecision]
accuracydeficit = Max[-Accuracy /@ {Re[%], Im[%]}]
(*
  0``-48.9342823110845 + 0``-48.95998064695299 I
  48.96
*)

extraprecision = 0;
extraprecision + accuracydeficit + $MachinePrecision
solWP = NSolve[eP == 0, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> extraprecision + accuracydeficit + $MachinePrecision];
eP /. solWP[[57]]
(*
  64.9146
  0``0.025698335868500944 + 0``0 I
*)

extraprecision = 2;
solWP = NSolve[eP == 0, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> extraprecision + accuracydeficit + $MachinePrecision];
eP /. solWP[[57]]
(*
  0``2.025698335868505 + 0``2. I
*)
```

The value of the  polynomial with `MachinePrecision` coefficients is still way off, for the same reasons as before, round-off error with insufficient precision.

```
e /. solWP[[57]]
(*
  -3.37129*10^45 - 2.92341*10^45 I
*)
```

Therefore to get solutions that will evaluate `eP` to `$MachinePrecision` accurately, we should pick the maximum accuracy deficit:

```
accuracydeficit = 
 Max[-Map[Accuracy, 
          Through[{Re, Im}[eP /. SetPrecision[sol, $MachinePrecision]]],
          {-1}]]
extraprecision = $MachinePrecision;
extraprecision + accuracydeficit + $MachinePrecision
solWP = NSolve[eP == 0, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> extraprecision + accuracydeficit + $MachinePrecision];
(*
  168.795
  200.704
*)
```

Check `solWP` (this returns the result with the lowest accuracy):

```
Through[{Re, Im}[eP /. solWP]] // Max
(*
  0.*10^-16
*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your so helpful and detailed answer. However, the equation is not zero and that's what is worrying me! Well, let me phrase my worry: how do I make sure that the numerical solutions are indeed near actual solutions? I guess I must use some sort of certification here! In that case, probably it is not a thing to discuss in this forum?

Comment: @John I feel foolish: See the update.  You can use `Solve` on the infinite-precision equation to verify the solutions -- or even find them!  You could make a plot near an approximate zero. For example, `With[{x0 = N[x /. solexact[[57]], 200]}, With[{eps = 2^Floor@Log2[Abs[$MachineEpsilon x0]]}, ListLinePlot[{Table[{k, Re@eP /. x -> x0 + k eps}, {k, -2, 2, 1/5}], Table[{k, Im@eP /. x -> x0 + k eps}, {k, -2, 2, 1/5}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}]]]`.  Then you can see where it crosses.