# Zeros of high degree polynomials

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, special-functions, polynomials

I am working with Hermite polynomials in Mathematica with the built-in function `HermiteH`. I want to compute the zeros of the polynomial `HermiteH[N,x]` for `N` as large as I can, as I am computing a Gaussian quadrature rule for integration of a smooth function.

I observe that, as `N` increases, the accuracy of `NSolve` drops dramatically. For instance,

```
HermiteH[18, x /. NSolve[HermiteH[18, x] == 0, x, Reals]]

{1., -0.28125, -0.0175781, -0.000732422, 0.000366211, -0.0000686646, 0.0000267029,
 9.53674*10^-7, 2.6226*10^-6, 2.6226*10^-6, 9.53674*10^-7, 0.0000267029, -0.0000686646,
 0.000366211, -0.000732422, -0.0175781, -0.28125, 1.}
```

You see, `Hermite[18, x]` evaluates at the first root as 1. Is there any way to improve the accuracy? Is there any built-in function to compute the roots of Hermite polynomials? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not use `Solve` instead of `NSolve`? Or add a `WorkingPrecision` option?

Comment: Don't use single argument `N`, as this will use machine numbers, and you will lose lots of precision due to subtractive cancellation.

Comment: Except for the 5th and 14th, roots `NSolve` seems to have found in each case the number `x` such that `Abs[Hermite[18, x]]` is as small as possible in a small neighborhood of `x`. Keep in mind that floating-point numbers are discrete. When the derivative of a function is large, as it is especially at the extreme roots, the difference between function values at adjacent floating-point numbers can seem large. The error in the residual should be bounded by `D[HermiteH[18, x], x] x $MachineEpsilon/2 /. {x -> x0}`, where `x0` is a root found by `NSolve`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51098/4999

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use machine numbers, as subtractive cancellation will cause enormous precision loss, as is common with high order polynomials.

You can either work with exact results using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
HermiteH[18, x /. Solve[HermiteH[18,x]==0,x,Reals]] //Simplify
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Or you can use the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision) option:

```
HermiteH[18, x /. NSolve[HermiteH[18,x]==0, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision->50]]
```

> {0.*10^-33, 0.*10^-35, 0.*10^-36, 0.*10^-37, 0.*10^-38, 0.*10^-38, 0.*10^-39, 
>    0.*10^-39, 0.*10^-40, 0.*10^-40, 0.*10^-39, 0.*10^-39, 0.*10^-38, 0.*10^-38, 
>    0.*10^-37, 0.*10^-36, 0.*10^-35, 0.*10^-33}

You can see that subtractive cancellation causes a precision loss of about 17 digits for the first and last roots.

Comment: A quibble: In my view, "subtractive cancellation" typical of polynomials is not the culprit here. One cannot avoid loss of (relative) precision in evaluating $f(x)$ if $f(x^*)=0$ and $x$ is close (enough) to $x^*$; it does not follow that there is a loss of accuracy. Indeed, on numeric inputs `HermiteH[integer, real]` uses a stable algorithm that avoids the subtractive precision loss that occurs in evaluating a polynomial in the power basis. Observe the extra loss of accuracy when `NSolve` is moved outside: `HermiteH[18, x] /. NSolve[HermiteH[18, x] == 0, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 50]`.

Answer (score 2):

For polynomials like [`HermiteH`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermiteH.html), these roots are represented in *Mathematica* as infinite-precision [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. The $k$th root of the $n$th Hermite polynomial is, with infinite precision, represented by

```
R[n_, k_] := Root[HermiteH[n, #] &, k]
```

What [Carl's use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201195/26598) of `Solve` does is simply to make a list of such `Root` objects. You can work with these objects analytically (using [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) etc.), or you can convert them to numerical.

For example, the 7th root of $H_{18}$ would be

```
r = R[18, 7]
(*    a root around -1.30...    *)
```

Numerically:

```
N[r]
(*    -1.30092    *)
N[r, 100]
(*    -1.300920858389617365666265554392610580218134639661226522772309775882782630084141194539623631652544514    *)
```

analytic transformations:

```
r^2 // RootReduce
(*    a root around 1.69...    *)
HermiteH[18, r] // RootReduce
(*    0    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

At least for this case, one can also consider getting the eigenvalues of the [Jacobi matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_operator) associated with the Hermite polynomials. Recall that these matrices are constructed from the [coefficients of the three-term recurrences](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.9.i) that generate the corresponding orthogonal polynomial. Applied to this case, we have:

```
With[{n = 18}, 
     s1 = Sort[Eigenvalues[N[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; Abs[j - k] == 1 :> Sqrt[Min[j, k]/2]},
                                         {n, n}]]]]]
   {-5.04836, -4.24812, -3.57377, -2.96138, -2.3863, -1.83553, -1.30092, -0.776683,
    -0.258268, 0.258268, 0.776683, 1.30092, 1.83553, 2.3863, 2.96138, 3.57377, 4.24812,
    5.04836}
```

For comparison purposes, let's compare that and a machine-precision evaluation of `NSolve[]` with an arbitrary-precision evaluation:

```
s2 = Sort[x /. NSolve[HermiteH[18, x], x]];

sb = Sort[x /. NSolve[HermiteH[18, x], x, WorkingPrecision -> 30]];

{Norm[sb - s1, ∞], Norm[sb - s2, ∞]}
   {4.44089*10^-15, 2.40696*10^-13}
```

and we see that the Jacobi-based method gives better results.